# Trouble in enabling esp32 PSAM in IDF menuconfig

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I enabled PSRAM on my esp32-wrover module by using idf.py menuconfig as shown in the image. In the log output of the module, PSRAM seems to be successfully initialized.

```
I (29) boot: ESP-IDF v4.4.6 2nd stage bootloader
I (29) boot: compile time 17:32:31
I (29) boot: Multicore bootloader
I (32) boot: chip revision: v3.0
I (36) boot.esp32: SPI Speed      : 40MHz
I (41) boot.esp32: SPI Mode       : DIO
I (45) boot.esp32: SPI Flash Size : 4MB
I (50) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...
I (55) boot: Partition Table:
I (59) boot: ## Label            Usage          Type ST Offset   Length
I (66) boot:  0 nvs              WiFi data        01 02 00009000 00006000
I (74) boot:  1 phy_init         RF data          01 01 0000f000 00001000
I (81) boot:  2 factory          factory app      00 00 00010000 00177000
I (89) boot: End of partition table
I (93) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=00010020 vaddr=3f400020 size=0f080h ( 61568) map
I (124) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0001f0a8 vaddr=3ffb0000 size=00f70h (  3952) load
I (125) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=00020020 vaddr=400d0020 size=22274h (139892) map
I (180) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0004229c vaddr=3ffb0f70 size=00d10h (  3344) load
I (182) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=00042fb4 vaddr=40080000 size=10e80h ( 69248) load
I (222) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000
I (222) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...
I (234) cpu_start: Multicore app
I (234) psram: This chip is ESP32-D0WD
I (236) spiram: Found 64MBit SPI RAM device
I (236) spiram: SPI RAM mode: flash 40m sram 40m
I (241) spiram: PSRAM initialized, cache is in low/high (2-core) mode.
I (248) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (252) cpu_start: Starting app cpu, entry point is 0x400813e4
0x400813e4: call_start_cpu1 at /home/cemo/esp/esp-idf-v4.4.6/components/esp_system/port/cpu_start.c:151

I (0) cpu_start: App cpu up.
I (1146) spiram: SPI SRAM memory test OK
I (1154) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
I (1154) cpu_start: cpu freq: 240000000
I (1154) cpu_start: Application information:
I (1157) cpu_start: Project name:     i2sdemo
I (1162) cpu_start: App version:      84e6d3a-dirty
I (1167) cpu_start: Compile time:     Dec 24 2023 17:32:27
I (1173) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256:  b76f6d3d6269d878...
I (1180) cpu_start: ESP-IDF:          v4.4.6
I (1184) cpu_start: Min chip rev:     v0.0
I (1189) cpu_start: Max chip rev:     v3.99 
I (1194) cpu_start: Chip rev:         v3.0
I (1199) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
I (1206) heap_init: At 3FFAE6E0 len 00001920 (6 KiB): DRAM
I (1212) heap_init: At 3FFB2700 len 0002D900 (182 KiB): DRAM
I (1219) heap_init: At 3FFE0440 len 00003AE0 (14 KiB): D/IRAM
I (1225) heap_init: At 3FFE4350 len 0001BCB0 (111 KiB): D/IRAM
I (1232) heap_init: At 40090E80 len 0000F180 (60 KiB): IRAM
I (1238) spiram: Adding pool of 4095K of external SPI memory to heap allocator
I (1247) spi_flash: detected chip: generic
I (1251) spi_flash: flash io: dio
I (1256) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
I (0) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on APP CPU.
I (1270) spiram: Reserving pool of 32K of internal memory for DMA/internal allocations
```

When I run the sketch,  it prints out:

```
PSRAM not detected
```

But `psramInit()` returns False. The last line of the above log is produced by the sketch (it is an ESP-IDF (arduino as component) project build by idf.py). (arduino-esp32 version 2.0.14 which compatible with ESP-IDF v.4.4.6). The contents of main.cpp is below.

```
#include "Arduino.h"

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    delay(250);

    if (psramInit()){
        printf("PSRAM init OK\n");
        printf("PSRAM size: %d\n", ESP.getFreePsram());
    }
    else{
        printf("PSRAM not detected!!\n");

    }
}

void loop()
{
    delay(10);
}
```

In platformio it is easy to enable PSRAM by adding `-DBOARD_HAS_PSRAM` build flag to the .ini file and `psraminit()` returns True. The sketch also returns true when compiled in Arduino IDE with PSRAM Enabled in the tools menu.

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work in ESP-IDF?